# MyClassLibrary.dll doesn't see my Assembly.resources.dll

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

I use Properies.Resources.resx file in my project for alternate values with russian language (Resources.ru.resx), but for some reason class Resources returns only defualt values.

I was strugling for two days with that problem and realised that I can add MyProject\bin\Debug\ru\AssemblyName.resources.dll as reference to my project and so I can use russian values. It resolves my problem for now, but I think that there should be some normal solution to the problem.

```cs
//it works with reference, but does not without it
Resources.Culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru");
TaskDialog.Show("Info", Properties.Resources.IsRoomName);
//returns "Имя комнаты"
```

As I understand, it should be done by itself but works only with already builded dll.